# .ash_history file is not created

Tags: linux, busybox, ash

I am using a login session in my ash machine.

My problem is, when executing `history` command in ash shell, it returns `0`. This is because the `.ash_history` is not created. I tried to triage the issue by debugging the `ash.c` code. Please find the code snippet of our interest. On analysis I found the Home directory is set to `NULL`, hence the underlined if condition is failed and ultimately reflects in `.ash_history` creation failure.

**Code snippet of ash.c**

```
 *#if MAX_HISTORY > 0 && ENABLE_FEATURE_EDITING_SAVEHISTORY
    if (iflag) {
        const char *hp = lookupvar("HISTFILE");
        if (!hp) {
            hp = lookupvar("HOME");
           ========================
            if(hp) {
           ===========
                hp = concat_path_file(hp, ".ash_history");
                setvar("HISTFILE", hp, 0);
                free(hp);
                hp = lookupvar("HISTFILE");
            }
        }
        if (hp)
            line_input_state->hist_file = hp;*
```

Can anyone help me in setting the `HOME` directory..If the home directory is some location, the if condition would have passed and `.ash_history` file will also be created, which resolves my issue.

Comment: Are you sure that the shell binary you are using was created with ENABLE_FEATURE_EDITING_SAVEHISTORY on? Normally HOME would be set by default (it's an environment variable).